# Filter on multiple fields in Mongoid subdocuments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I want to query for documents that have a subdocument that contains two values.

I have a main document, Account, that contains none or more sales subdocuments.  Each sale has a sale_price and sale_date.  I only want accounts that have a sale subdocument with a sale_price greater than 0 and sale_date in the last 4 years.

Here is what I've tried;

```
Account.and("sales.sale_date" => {"$gt" => Date.today - 4.years}, "sales.sale_price" => {"$gt" => 0})
```

This returns accounts that have "any" sales in the last 4 years and have "any" sale with a sale_price > 0.  I want only Accounts have a sale with both criteria true on the same document.
Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As happens so often, more investigation after asking a question turns up a solution.  The elem_match method appears to do what I need.
Here's what I came up with;

```
Account.elem_match(sales: {:sale_date.gt => Date.today - 4.years, :sale_price.gt => 0})
```